# jQuery 'Select Multiple' with 'N' Columns

Tags: c#, jquery, html, html-table, html-select

I'm working on a project which has a ListBox (**tag: select multiple**) that should have more than one column.

Actually, that ListBox is a real ListBox, but It must show like a Table with columns (**tag: table**).

Example (If were like this):

```
<select multiple>
    <option> <tr> <t> Hello </td> <td> World </td> <td> ! </td> </tr </option>
    ...
</select>

_____________________________________
|  Hello   |     World     |   !  | |
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
|  Hello   |     World     |   !  | |
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
|  Hello   |     World     |   !  | |
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
|  Hello   |     World     |   !  | |
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
|  Hello   |     World     |   !  | |
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a fixed-width font, its just a case of laying it out correctly. There is no official listbox/tabulated select in HTML.

```css
select {
  font-family: "Andale Mono", "Monotype.com", monospace;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option>| Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; | World | ! |</option>
  <option>| Goodbye&nbsp; | World | ! |</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tab` character (`&#9;`) like this:

```
<select multiple>
  <option>Hello &#9; Hello &#9; Hello</option>
  <option>Hello &#9; Hello &#9; Hello</option>
</select>
```